# Strange Output in Expect Recordings: How to eliminate, and any reasons why?

Tags: bash, fedora, expect

So, I have switched to Fedora from Debian recently, and have noticed something odd in the default Fedora BASH shell.

If I run `autoexpect` and record commands, the following sorts of output gets generated:

```
# demo of the recording

autoexpect 
env > foo
Ctrl-D
```

```
# the script expect statement recording

# notice that expect recorded output prior to sending the command!

set timeout -1
spawn $env(SHELL)
match_max 100000

expect -exact "^[\]777;notify;Command completed;env > foo^[\\^[\]777;precmd^[\\^[\]0;chris@localhost:~^[\\^[\]7;file://localhost.localdomain/home/chris^[\\\[chris@localhost ~\]\$ "
send -- "env > foo\r"
expect -exact "env > foo\r
^[\]777;preexec^[\\^[\]777;notify;Command completed;env > foo^[\\^[\]777;precmd^[\\^[\]0;chris@localhost:~^[\\^[\]7;file://localhost.localdomain/home/chris^[\\\[chris@localhost ~\]\$ "
```

I will not see any of this what looks like multi-processing junk in a similar recording in, say, debian.

Even worse, here is a first class linux distribution, and `autoexpect` flat out fails to run after I record a simple macro due to this apparent shell-abstraction layer.

This seems to be due to the fact that my actions in the fedora shell are in a shell within a shell, and `expect` actually records the auto-generated flag response *before* `send -- "env > foo\r"` is recorded.

Further, I have shelled into a remote `fedora` machine where none of this occurs.

What is going on here?

Comment: Your Fedora bash prompt is different from your Debian bash prompt.

Comment: @glennjackman sorry, I did not add everything.  I am shelling from a fedora prompt to a fedora destination.  In the destination install of `fedora 32`, there is none of that subshell activity.  In my source install of `fedora 32`, there is.  Both of them are brand new.

Comment: So, what's in the default fedora prompt? what does `declare -p PS1 PROMPT_COMMAND` show?

Comment: @glennjackman `declare -- PS1="[\\u@\\h \\W]\\\$ "
declare -- PROMPT_COMMAND="__vte_prompt_command"`

Comment: OK, now `type __vte_prompt_command` should contain that "notify" stuff. If you don't want it, `unset PROMPT_COMMAND` in your .bashrc.

Comment: @glennjackman got it -- thank you, I see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Fedora bash prompt is different from your Debian bash prompt.

You can do something like this in expect:

```
set prompt "$ "

spawn bash
send "unset PROMPT_COMMAND; PS1='$prompt'\r"

expect $prompt
send "env > foo\r"

expect $prompt
send "\x04"    ;# Ctrl-D
expect eof
```